# Disable Button that triggered an ActivityforResult

Tags: android, button, onclick, onactivityresult

My code goes like this:
- A button triggers one Activity on result, meaning that the activity should give back a result. 
- When the activity finishes and returns to the activity where the button was clicked, I would like to disable this button.

I created the buttons dynamically, this is why I have to use them through View v on the onClick method.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    b= (Button)v;

    Intent ir_a_emociones = new Intent(this,emociones_votar.class);
    ir_a_emociones.putExtra("alumno",alumno);
    ir_a_emociones.putExtra("asignatura",b.getText().toString());
    startActivityForResult(ir_a_emociones, 55);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 55) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "¡Gracias!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           ***--> here the button that triggered the intent should be disabled.***
        }
    }
}
```

There it is the onclick and the onActivityResult. I don't know how to referenciate back the button. B is a button, but as far as I know, it just let me get the references inside onClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `setEnabled(boolean value)` of button on activity result. For more detail open [Android documentation link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setEnabled(boolean))

```
private Button b;
// 
public void onClick(View v) {
    b= (Button)v;

    Intent ir_a_emociones = new Intent(this,emociones_votar.class);
    ir_a_emociones.putExtra("alumno",alumno);
    ir_a_emociones.putExtra("asignatura",b.getText().toString());
    startActivityForResult(ir_a_emociones, 55);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 55) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "¡Gracias!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if(b!= null){
             b.setEnable(false) // false :: Disable button, true :: Enable button
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I supposed that after opening the onActivityResult would lose the status on the activity, but it keeps as it is until the result finishes, that is why the confusion of my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome.. Keep Coding.. :) @M.M.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I don't get the negative votes. I don't know if my question is wrongly formed, or it has been answered already (which I didn't find) or it is too basic and people here expects higher level questions.

Answer (score 0):

Save the reference of b as private attribute of the class, then use the attribute in onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 55) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "¡Gracias!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (b != null)
                b.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```